# How to access JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a multiple part array via ajax to a PHP function.

This is my JS:

```
var datastring = {
        newEmailForm: newEmailForm,
        properties: properties
    };

    //got the data, make the ajax request
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                action: 'elegantSendEmail',
                datastring: datastring
            },
            url: ajaxurl
        })
    })
```

This is the array thats being sent:

```
action  elegantSendEmail
  datastring[newEmailForm][0][] {…}
    0   email
    1   title
    2   Message
  datastring[properties][0][]   {…}
    0   31466
    1   value1
    2   value1
  datastring[properties][1][]   {…}
    0   31440
    1   value2
    2   value2
```

Here is my attempt at trying to get at it via PHP but i just get nothing in my response.

```
function elegantSendEmail(){
   var_dump($_POST);
  wp_die();
}
```

Here is the result of the dump from my console:

```
array(2) { 
  ["action"]=> string(16) "elegantSendEmail" 
  ["datastring"]=> array(1) { 
    ["newEmailForm"]=> array(1) { 
     [0]=> array(3) { 
      [0]=> string(5) "email" 
      [1]=> string(5) "title" 
      [2]=> string(17) "Youe message here" 
      } 
     } 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: You're sending POST data, not JSON data.

Comment: There's no problem sending JSON by POST @Dormilich

Comment: You have to first `json_decode`, then you can access the values. Also the values you are looking for are `$json['datastring']['newemailform']`

Comment: What do you see when you do `print_r($_POST['newEmailForm'][0])`?

Comment: check what you are getting from print_r($_POST['datastring']);

Comment: Also what do you mean "this is the array that is being sent"? That doesn't make much sense. It's not an array format that I recognise for a start and it's not clear in which part of your JS code it is being sent.

Comment: @geoidesic, its the array format from the console in browser. Ill clean it up and write the syntax properly if you prefer.

Comment: @TobiasF. Give me a second to make some changes and Ill come back.

Comment: var_dump your `$_POST` to see if it returns anything at first. Then post the result you are getting and we can take it from there.

Comment: @pr1nc3 Ive edited the question to show my PHP function itself and Ive dumped the $_POST into the console, result below.

Comment: Ok now you've changed the question, so none of the comments make sense anymore. Previously you had a json_decode in there now it's gone. So now it's all just one big confusion. When you edit questions, you should update them with notes, not fundamentally change them. If you're getting the array in your console then what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[More information How to access data with json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST['datastring']['newEmailForm'][0], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
function elegantSendEmail() {
 $obj = $_POST['datastring']['newEmailForm'][0][0];
 var_dump($obj);
 //Above dump shows 'email'
 wp_die(); 
}
```

Comment: more description about your code helps users to understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send data with proper json format in ajax. for example

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on your answer and after `var_dump` the `$_POST`  result we see that you pass an array and not a json object. So you can access it's fields like a normal array.

```
$obj=$_POST['datastring']['newEmailForm'][0][0]  // will get you the email

$obj=$_POST['datastring']['newEmailForm'][0][1]  // will get you the title

$obj=$_POST['datastring']['newEmailForm'][0][2]  // will get you the message
```